# Oracle: how can I fire a warning when a value turns negative?

Tags: database, oracle, oracle10g

I'm using this to discount values from plazas_disponibles. How can I make Oracle fire a warning when plazas_disponibles gets to 0?

```
SELECT F.NRO_VUELO, M.CAPACIDAD, M.CAPACIDAD - COALESCE((
SELECT count(*) FROM PLAN_VUELO P
WHERE P.NRO_VUELO = F.NRO_VUELO
       ), 0) as PLAZAS_DISPONIBLES
FROM VUELO F
      INNER JOIN MODELO M ON M.ID = F.CODIGO_AVION;
```

Comment: Who are you supposed to warn?

Comment: How are you supposed to warn them ? Pager, SMS, email, twitter, RSS ?

Answer (score 1):

You might want to create a materialized view based upon your query:

```
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW PLAZAS_DISPONIBLES_MAT_VIEW
  REFRESH ON COMMIT
  AS
    SELECT F.NRO_VUELO, M.CAPACIDAD, M.CAPACIDAD - COALESCE((
    SELECT count(*) FROM PLAN_VUELO P
    WHERE P.NRO_VUELO = F.NRO_VUELO
           ), 0) as PLAZAS_DISPONIBLES
    FROM VUELO F
          INNER JOIN MODELO M ON M.ID = F.CODIGO_AVION;
```

and then add a `check constraint` to ensure that the count(*) of that query is not equal to 0:

```
ALTER TABLE PLAZAS_DISPONIBLES_MAT_VIEW 
  ADD CONSTRAINT PLAZAS_DISPONIBLES_CHECK CHECK (PLAZAS_DISPONIBLES != 0);
```

I have chosen `!= 0`, but maybe, you need `> 0` or `< 0`. It's up to you to define the requirement.